# UIPickerView inside static UITableViewCell animation on cell height update issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static `UITableView` in which I have a `UIPickerView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. When triggering `didSelectRowAt` it is supposed to toggle the height of the cell that has the `UIPickerView`. I use `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` to change the height of the cell. It looks right when expanding but when collapsing, the `UIPickerView` doesn't animate and collapses faster than the cell does. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have made sure all views are set to `true` for `clipToBounds` on the `UITableViewCell`, ContentView (of the `UITableViewCell`) and `UIPickerView`. I have tried to wrap the beginUpdates/endUpdates in a `DispatchQueue.main.async`. My `UIPickerView` is using AutoLayout and (leading, trailing, top, bottom) edges are equal to Content View of the cell. I am using a StoryBoard for my UI.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
        case (1,1):
            showPicker = !showPicker
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        default:
            ()
        }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
        case (1, 1):
            if !showDueDate {
                return 0
            }
        case (1, 2):
            if !showPicker {
                return 0
            }
        case (_, _):
            break
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

I expected the animation to be smooth and `UIPickerView` to collapse alongside the `UITabeViewCell`.

see gif to see issue

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/LQ37DzbGKnGHisvvx9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My bottom constraint of the `UIPickerView` was set to the bottom of the content view, constant was 0. Changed it to <= 0 and it fixed it. Don't understand why 0 didn't work. Atleast I figured it out...

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section), with: .fade)` instead of `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`. It will give you a smooth animation when animating table changes.

Comment: unfortunately I've tried different reloads animations types and they haven't worked correctly. .fade actually makes the picker view fade away and not come back.

Comment: where is the code that returns the size of the cells when it's not hidden? I only see it returns 0

Comment: `return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)` tells the tableView to get it from the storyboard.

Comment: I would be more explicit. try to return an actual height in the heightForRow method, and see if it changes anything, if not- check the constraints of the picker.

Comment: tried that. doesn't change anything. constraints are the edges of content view of uitableview cell.